# Pass back parameters in ASP.NET Web API GrantResourceOwnerCredentials

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to pass back some parameters from ASP.NET Web API after the user has logged in.

I am basing my work on this nice tutorial:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

I can see on the demo page that he sends back userName for example.

I create my own provider that inherits from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
And this is what I do:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{ 
    ....

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", user.Role));

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { 
            "userName", user.UserName
        },
        { 
            "role", user.Role
        }
    });

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

This is how I hook it up:

```
var OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

As I understand it, the AuthenticationProperties dictionary should be passed back in the JSON response to the client. But for some reason I don't get my additional parameters back. This is what I get:

{"access_token":"G4S1PXdNbtAHLFBo......","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":86399}

I have spent alot of time trying to figure this one out, can anyone see that I am missing?

Answer (score 11):

I found my issue. It seems as if I misunderstood the properties dictionary.

I added this method:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

It basically takes the entries in the dictionary and adds it to the response. My mistake was to assume that would be done automatically for me.

Comment: I can't believe how long it took to figure this out. I saw tons of examples of adding the properties, but this is the first I've seen needing to override this method to get them in the response.